# does the elementary transformation to a matrix change the rank?

Tags: matrix-rank

Does the Rank decrease if the elements of a row are reduced to zero by elementary transformation ?

I think Rank doesn't change because Rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent row, which means the row which will be reduced to zero was never counted in finding the Rank of the matrix, so it will not change the Rank if it's reduced to zero.

But the solution in my reference book says Rank decreases if the elements of a row are reduced to zero by elementary transformation.

I am confused because I cant' find any logical explanation for it.

So once more I will type the question properly:

Q. By applying elementary Transformation to a matrix, it's rank:

(A) Does not change

(B) Decreases if the elements of a row are reduced to zero by elementary transformation.

Comment: Elementary row operations are reverrsiuble. So if the rank went down, that would mean the number of independent rows went down, but the latter number is just the dimension of the row space and so is constant under reversible linear operations,

Comment: You have got all your reasoning right. Look at it from equation view point. These manipulations do not change the solvability and the number of solutions.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is (B) right? @coffeemath

Comment: @PranavPeethambaran  The answer is (A), Rank does not change.

Comment: @Shailesh: Ok. Thanks for correcting me! :)